# How can i write update query for check this plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm new in database and can write very simple query ,i have two table:
table Maintable with this design:
[image]

And table karkard with this design:
[image]

want to write this update query in sql server:

```
update table MainTable
set score=score+karkard.karkard
where maintable.phone=karkard.phonenumber
```

How can i write that query?thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `UPDATE` query unless I'm missing something in your question:

```
UPDATE MainTable
  SET  score = mt.score + k.karkard
  FROM MainTable mt
    INNER JOIN karkard k ON k.phonenumber = mt.phone
```

Comment: Thanks my friend,i'm beginner,and so thanks for answer,please wait test your query

Answer (score 0):

```
update mt
set
mt.score=mt.score+k.karkard
from
maintable mt
join
karkard k
on k.phonenumber=mt.phonenumber
```